# XenServer 6.5 upgrade: NVIDIA GRID K1 gives "PAT Configuration unsupported"

Tags: virtualization, xenserver, drivers, graphics-processing-unit

We have two Supermicro SYS2027GR-TR2 servers that were running XenServer 6.2 SP1. Each system has one NVIDIA GRID K1 video card installed. We just upgraded the servers to XenServer 6.5 by doing a clean install, and upon restarting and installing the nvidia driver rpm with `rpm -iv NVIDIA-vgx-xenserver-6.5-340.57.x86_64.rpm`, our cards are not healthy per XenServer.

Output of `lsmod | grep nvidia`:

```
nvidia              10548578  26
```

Output of `dmesg | grep -E "NVRM|nvidia"`:

```
[   23.307736] nvidia: module license 'NVIDIA' taints kernel.
[   23.353034] nvidia 0000:06:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[   23.353359] nvidia 0000:07:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[   23.353613] nvidia 0000:08:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[   23.353847] nvidia 0000:09:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0003)
[   23.354119] NVRM: loading NVIDIA UNIX x86_64 Kernel Module  340.57  Mon Oct 27 14:36:29 PDT 2014
[   23.354129] NVRM: PAT configuration unsupported.
```

XenServer does not show any GPU tab and VMs cannot be assigned to use a vGPU, only a pass-thru GPU. We've followed the install instructions included with the nvidia driver package. Has anyone else run into this?

Comment: This might be due to the new license requirement in XS6.5 can you try applying the XenServer for xendesktop + license?

Comment: @Jared - It looks like that might be part of the issue. We don't have a license for anything currently but we can purchase one or get a trial and see if that fixes the issue.